# Process new item in request error callback

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to add an `errback` function to every `Request` to catch DNS lookup failures, timeouts and such. Upon catching them, I would like to submit a new item to be processed in the pipelines to record (in the database) that URL x failed with error y.

I can think of two theoretical ways to do it (but in practice I don't know how to do either).
1) Somehow patch into the crawler engine and add a new item to the item processing queue.
2) Manually call the respective pipelines (I only need to call one to be fair), but accessing them probably goes something like option 1, somehow need to patch to the engine and then hack-ishly find the pipelines...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out *a* way of doing it, not sure if this is the best or the worst way.

All my requests receive an `errback` callback as suggested in the [docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-errbacks-to-catch-exceptions-in-request-processing). The `errback` is this:

```
def process_failed_request(self, failure):
    status = 'Unknown problem'

    if failure.check(HttpError) or failure.check(IgnoreRequest):
        return
    elif failure.check(twisted_errors.DNSLookupError):
        status = 'Server not found'
    elif failure.check(TimeoutError, twisted_errors.TCPTimedOutError):
        status = '408'
    elif failure.check(twisted_errors.SSLError):
        status = 'SSL error'
    elif failure.check(twisted_errors.ConnectError):
        status = 'Connection error'

    item = {
        'visited_page': LightRequest(None, url=failure.request.url, status_code=status),
    }

    # Force scrapy to process the failed item as it was a normal item
    self.crawler.engine.scraper.slot.itemproc_size += 1
    dfd = self.crawler.engine.scraper.itemproc.process_item(item, self)
    dfd.addBoth(self.crawler.engine.scraper._itemproc_finished, item, None, self)
```

Don't pay any mind to what happens in the upper part, but the three bottom lines are the magic. First line increments the item processing queue counter to limit the `CONCURRENT_ITEMS` correctly. Second line calls the processing and third line adds the callbacks that are added by Scrapy for every item processed. The `None` argument is the `response` value that could actually be put in, too, at least for some errors. You can access it from `failure.value.response` but I don't care about that for now.

Oh, and if it was unclear, then `self` is the `Spider` of course.

PS! Since this is pretty heavily dependent on scrapy engine, then the version I'm using is 1.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your [downloader middleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#writing-your-own-downloader-middleware) and implement the `process_exception` method.

You have access to the request object, so you can write the details to your database, and then return a new request.

Comment: Yep, I thought about a middleware but the blocker was that I wanted to write the data in a pipeline, because I have a pipeline where I store all the status codes for all the URLs and when the spider closes, I write the whole shebang to the database. Writing the status codes from multiple places one by one would be a hassle. I also considered scheduling a new request from the middleware, but if the server returns 500 for example and I schedule a new one, then how do I make the request pass and the data end up in the pipeline... Complicated. So for now I prefer my solution. Thanks though!

Comment: So, I think you still can use the middleware to capture the errors, and pass them in the response meta dict. Then when creating the items, you can pass to them what you need from the meta dict, and so you can use the data later in the pipeline. The middleware will be responsible to yield new requests, and the item pipeline will be responsible for the storage.

Comment: If the DNS & timeout errors are passed to the `process_exception` method, then this would work, provided that we create a new Response in the middleware. I haven't tested it, but theoretically it could work.